# Invalid UILabel content when clicking on a cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` with custom cells:

```
class customChatCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userMessage: UILabel!
```

And I have a code for open URL contained in the `userMessage`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let identifier = "ClientCell"
    self.cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? customChatCell
    self.cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none

    // Unpack message from Firebase DataSnapshot
    let messageSnapshot = self.messages[indexPath.row]
    guard let message = messageSnapshot.value as? [String: String] else { return cell }
    let name = message[Constants.MessageFields.name] ?? ""

    if let imageURL = message[Constants.MessageFields.imageURL] {
        self.cell.userName.text = name

        self.cell.hiddenLabel.isHidden = true
        self.cell.userMessage.text = imageURL

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(FCViewController.tapFunction))

        self.cell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        if self.cell.userName.text == Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName {
            self.cell.userName.textAlignment = .right
            self.cell.userMessage.textAlignment = .right
            self.cell.hiddenLabel.textAlignment = .right
        } else {
            self.cell.userName.textAlignment = .left
            self.cell.userMessage.textAlignment = .left
            self.cell.hiddenLabel.textAlignment = .left
        }
        self.cell.setNeedsLayout()

    } else {
        let text = message[Constants.MessageFields.text] ?? ""

        self.cell.userName.text = name
        self.cell.userMessage.text = text

        self.cell.hiddenLabel.isHidden = true
        self.cell.hiddenLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        if self.cell.userName.text == Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName {
            self.cell.userName.textAlignment = .right
            self.cell.userMessage.textAlignment = .right
        } else {
            self.cell.userName.textAlignment = .left
            self.cell.userMessage.textAlignment = .left
        }
    }
    return cell
}

@objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var url = URL(string: self.cell.userMessage.text!)!
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

But when clicking on any cell, only the link that is contained in the **last cell** always opens. No matter which cell I click.

**How to make it so that when you click on a cell, the specific link that is contained in a particular `userMessage` opens?**

Comment: how are you keeping `self.cell` reference?

Comment: basically as per your implementation `self.cell` will always contains reference of your last cell. you have to keep track of every index to perform click on each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set Tag to each Cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let identifier = "ClientCell"
self.cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? customChatCell

...

    self.cell.tag = indexPath.row // SETTING TAG TO EACH CELL. 0,1,2...

...
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(FCViewController.tapFunction))
    self.cell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

...
}

@objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("CELL_TAG_NUMBER.  ", sender.view.tag)
    let messageSnapshot = self.messages[sender.view.tag] THIS WILL GIVE, 0,1,2...

    print("Exact_URL.  ", messageSnapshot)

    //var url = URL(string: self.cell.userMessage.text!)!
    //UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: Do not use a tag to represent a cell's index. Determine the index path from the cell when it is tapped.

Comment: Ok, it works, i see message: Exact_URL.   Snap (-LSmSqM3C5d7-BI-qzV_) {
    imageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amkkfinal-ios.appspot.com/o/myFiles%2F8980.jpg?alt=media&token=45559866-24fc-40ac-b9b9-e4d3407a1f4c";
    name = "\U0410\U0440\U0442\U0435\U043c \U0418\U043b\U044c\U0438\U043d\U0441\U043a\U0438\U0439";
}          How can I put the imageUrl from this to var url?

Comment: How u are doing this? guard let message = messageSnapshot.value as? [String: String] else { return cell }
    let name = message[Constants.MessageFields.name] ?? "" if let imageURL = message[Constants.MessageFields.imageURL] {self.cell.userMessage.text = imageURL}. By this way, you can get URL.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting url from another way.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add a tap gesture to the cell, a UITableView has a delegate method for when a cell is selected. if you use that then you also don't need to track your cells using a tag(Not GOOD!), instead you will use the direct indexPath of that specific cell.

implement this method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Now you have your selected cell
    let messageSnapshot = self.messages[indexPath.row]
    print(messageSnapshot)

}
```